# mongoDB watch() collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I am trying to watch for changes in my collection but I am getting the following error:
"MongoError: Majority read concern requested, but it is not supported by the storage engine."

The answer seems to be: "To use watch you need to use replica set which is not part of mLab".

But i have a paid plan with a replica set. My connection to mlab looks like this.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds327925-a0.mlab.com:27925,ds327925-a1.mlab.com:27925/<dbname>?replicaSet=rs-ds327925');

const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');
const changeStream = taskCollection.watch();

changeStream.on('change', (change) => {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Majority read concern [requires WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-majority/#storage-engine-support).

Availability of WiredTiger in mlab is [limited to "dedicated" plans](https://docs.mlab.com/faq/#why-am-i-getting-the-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-storage-engines-that-support-document-level-locking-error), apparently.

Besides upgrading your plan, you could also consider migrating to MongoDB Atlas.

In MongoDB 4.2+ change streams [do not require majority read concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/), but I don't imagine 4.2 is available in mlab either.

Comment: Migrated to MongoDB Atlas. Works fine now! Thank you